# All my field in the variable turned to NA when I used the as.Date command to convert Character to Date in R. Anything wrong with my code?

Tags: r

I am not sure what is wrong. I downloaded some data in Json format and managed to extract the data that I need out as data frame and I saved it as data2

Basically the data2 looks like below:

```
> head(data2)
    month                                                  level_1  value
1 1990-01 Consultation Fees At Polyclinics & General Practitioners 48.507
2 1990-01                               Medical & Dental Treatment 39.986
3 1990-01                                                   Petrol  0.000
4 1990-01                              Overall Bus And Train Fares 62.543
5 1990-01                                               Taxi Fares 52.924
6 1990-01                   Miscellaneous Fees For Primary Schools 31.610

> str(data2)
'data.frame':   2656 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ month  : chr  "1990-01" "1990-01" "1990-01" "1990-01" ...
 $ level_1: Factor w/ 8 levels "Consultation Fees At Polyclinics & General Practitioners",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 ...
 $ value  : num  48.5 40 0 62.5 52.9 ...
```

I managed to change level_1 to a factor and value to numeric. But when I tried to use as.Date to change the $month to a date class, all the observations in $month turned to NA.

```
> data2$month<- as.Date(data2$month, format = "%Y-%m")
> head(data2)
  month                                                  level_1  value
1  <NA> Consultation Fees At Polyclinics & General Practitioners 48.507
2  <NA>                               Medical & Dental Treatment 39.986
3  <NA>                                                   Petrol  0.000
4  <NA>                              Overall Bus And Train Fares 62.543
5  <NA>                                               Taxi Fares 52.924
6  <NA>                   Miscellaneous Fees For Primary Schools 31.610
```

Confused. Please help.

Comment: Date needs a day.  Either paste with 1 or use `as.yearmon` from `zoo`

Comment: I have library(zoo) as well and I used format(as.yearmon(data2$month), "%Y-%m"). But it can't how will you do it?

Comment: If the intention is to to convert to `Date` class, then `as.Date(as.yearmon("1990-01"))
[1] "1990-01-01"`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. In the month column, there are many observations, how to convert all the dates? All the dates are from 1990-01 to 2017-05 and there are thousands of observations.

Comment: It is working for me as I showed.  Also `doesn't work` is not very useful for understanding the problem

Comment: What I mean is, if I use as.Date(as.yearmon("1990-01")) [1] "1990-01-01", nothing change. It is still in character class

Comment: Have you checked the `class` i.e. `class(as.Date(as.yearmon("1990-01")))
#[1] "Date"`

Comment: > class(as.Date(as.yearmon("1990-01"))) #[1] "Date"
[1] "Date". But what is the command will you use to convert the entire data2$month variable into a data class?

Comment: Which is the command to convert the entire column to a data class?

Comment: It is the same command except that you specify the column `data2$month <- as.Date(as.yearmon(data2$month))`

Comment: [994] "2000-05-01" "2000-05-01" "2000-05-01"
 [997] "2000-05-01" "2000-05-01" "2000-05-01"
[1000] "2000-05-01"
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 1656 entries ]
> class(data2$month)
[1] "character"

Comment: All these are still characters after I used as.Date(as.yearmon(data2$month))

Comment: Have u assigned the output to the original column as I showed above?

Comment: Thanks Akrun, you made my day. data2$month<-as.Date(as.yearmon(data2$month)) solved the problem. Once again, thanks you for you help.

Comment: Akrun, how about if the date format is just "1999", how to convert it to a date since as.yearmon command will return a "Date of length 0"?

Answer (score 0):

As quick answer I recommend spread it first and add day column, then unite and change with as.Date

```
df<- separate(month, c(year,month), sep= "-")
df$day <- rep("01",nrow(df))

df<- unite(df, date, c(year,month,day), sep = "/"
df$date<- ad.Date("%Y/%m/%d")
```

As for my knowledge as.Date function need day.